# Toggle visibility of text box based on status of check box -jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle, visibility

I had some help with this earlier and yet somehow I can no longer get it to work.  I need a text box to appear if an 'other' check box is checked, and dissappear when it isn't checked.  Anyone know what gives?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Even More Rounded Corners (Single Image Approach) Using CSS - Simple Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/dialog.css" media="screen" />

<style type="text/css">
/* basic formatting */
body {font:76% normal verdana,tahoma,arial,"sans serif";}
h1 {font:2.5em georgia,"times new roman",helvetica,verdana,"sans serif";}
p {line-height:1.6em;}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { $('#other').change(function(){ 
    $('#otherrace').parent().toggle( this.checked );
});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="demo">

<!-- most basic example -->
<div class="dialog">
 <div class="content">
  <div class="t"></div>
  <!-- Your content goes here -->
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <form id="form1" method="post" action=""><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="16%">First Name</td>
    <td width="32%"><input type="text" name="fname" size="25" maxlength="25" /></td>
    <td width="9%">Street</td>
    <td width="24%"><input type="text" name="street" size="40" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MI</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mi" size="3" maxlength="1" /></td>
    <td>City</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="city" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" size="25" maxlength="25" /></td>
    <td>County</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DOB</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="age" size="5" maxlength="3" /></td>
    <td>ZIP</td>
    <td><input name="zip" type="text" size="5" maxlength="7" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Gender</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td>
      <p></p>
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender_0" />
          </label>
        Female<br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender_1" />
          Male</label>
        <br />
      </p>
      <p></p>
   </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>


<p>What race do you consider yourself?  Please choose all that apply.</p><input type="checkbox" name="race" value="asian" />Asian<br /><input type="checkbox" name="race" value="hawaii" />Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander<br /><input type="checkbox" name="race" value="noanswer" />Choose not to answer<br /><input type="checkbox" name="race" value="other" id="other" />Other, specify<br /><div id="other"><input style="display:none;" type="text" size="25" maxlength="25" id="otherrace" /></div><br />
<div id="race"></div>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<p align="right"><input type="button" align="right" value="Next page" onclick="window.location.href='registry2.html'" /></p>




</form>


  <br/>



  <br/><br/><br/>
 </div>
 <div class="b"><div></div></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#other').change(function(){ 
        $('#otherrace').toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/2hw89/

Also, you have two elements with id="other" in your document, which is *invalid*.

Lastly, you can make your form a tiny bit more usable by focusing on the 'other' text input when the checkbox is checked, saving the user from having to home in on it, like this:

```
$('#other').change(function(){ 
    $('#otherrace').toggle(this.checked).focus();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/2hw89/1/

Comment: In addition to what karim79 pointed out regarding your multiple elements with the same id, you have a `<script>` tag that's not closed.  Syntax errors in your jQuery, but if you use karim79's code, that'll be fixed.

Comment: i still cannot get the code to work..i see it working in the example just fine.  i've copied and pasted and it still won't appear...any clues?

Comment: JS---$(document).ready(function() { $('#other').change(function(){ $('#otherrace').toggle(this.checked).focus(); }); -------html---<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
 

<p>What race do you consider yourself?  Please choose all that apply.</p><input type="checkbox" name="race" value="other1" id="other" />Other, specify<br /><input style="display:none;" type="text" size="25" maxlength="25" id="otherrace" /><br />