# Why is my simple JQuery tutorial attempt not responding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a very simple coding example work, but for an unknown reason, it is not responding.

The example I am trying to replicate is found here: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/2hw89/1/
It is an answer to the following SO question: [Toggle visibility of text box based on status of check box -jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392169/toggle-visibility-of-text-box-based-on-status-of-check-box-jquery)

Here is my code. I have embedded another checkbox, to test if I could call a basic onclick-listener-function. It works. The other checkbox is however not reacting when clicked, even though the exact same code works in the example. Do you know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#other').change(function() {
            alert("Hello World!");
            $('#otherrace').toggle(this.checked).focus();
        });
    });

</script>
<script>
    function test(){
    alert("Test is working!");
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="race" value="other" id="other">Other,
    Specify
    <br />
    <input style="display: none;" type="text" size="25" maxlength="25"
        id="otherrace" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="test()" name="test" value="test"
        id="test">testing
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[script element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) cannot have both src and body

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--or use the address as http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#other').change(function() {
            alert("Hello World!");
            $('#otherrace').toggle(this.checked).focus();
        });
    });

</script>
```

[Script.src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src)

> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be
>   used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
>   document. script elements with an src attribute specified should not
>   have a script embedded within its tags.

Also, if you are loading the page from a local files system, using a protocol like `file://....` then you need to specify the `http` protocol in the jQuery url like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: This is the easiest and fastest answer I have gotten. Even though the answer is a basic thing I should have known, it might have taken me a LOT of time to think to look for the right answer. Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much. I'll accept the answer soon, as there is a timer counting down, blocking for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`